# wxPython/wxGtk Platform Issue: Cannot Force Refresh/Update on Opening Modal Dialog Panel

Tags: python, gtk, wxpython, wxwidgets

*System info:*

```
Linux: Lubuntu/Ubuntu Jammy 21.04.1 x86_64
wxPython: python3-wxgtk4.0 4.0.7
wxWidgets: libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-0
Gtk: libgtk-3-0 3.24.33
```

I think I am having a platform related issue. I create a `wx.Dialog` but cannot force the layout to update consistently on the Modal window when it is opened.

*Code:*

```
class Dialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, "A Dialog Window",
                parent.GetPosition(), wx.Size(640, 480),
                wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE|wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

        tabs = wx.Notebook(self)

        # create first page with centered text
        panel1 = wx.Panel(tabs, wx.ID_ANY)
        layout1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        layout1.AddStretchSpacer()
        layout1.Add(wx.StaticText(panel1, label="Centered"), 1,
                wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        layout1.AddStretchSpacer()

        panel1.SetSizer(layout1)
        panel1.SetAutoLayout(True)
        panel1.Layout()

        # create second page with non-centered text
        panel2 = wx.Panel(tabs, wx.ID_ANY)
        layout2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        layout2.Add(wx.StaticText(panel2, label="Not Centered"), 1)

        panel2.SetSizer(layout2)
        panel2.SetAutoLayout(True)
        panel2.Layout()

        tabs.AddPage(panel1, "Page 1")
        tabs.AddPage(panel2, "Page 2")

class Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test", wx.Point(50, 50),
                wx.Size(200, 200))

        btn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "PUSH ME")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

    def onButton(self, evt):
        dia = Dialog(self)
        dia.ShowModal()
        #dia.Destroy()
```

I open & close the dialog multiple times but the text is not always centered or fully drawn. The times that it is centered & drawn correctly the system shows this message (error?): `gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkNotebook`

If I don't call `Destroy()` on the dialog, once it is aligned correctly on opening it will be aligned subsequently.

I have tried to force redrawing by calling `Refresh()` & `Update()` on the dialog, the notebook, & the panel in the constructor & on the dialog after instantiation & before calling `ShowModal()`. The only thing that has worked is to instantiate the dialog as a class member in the main window constructor (& omit calling `wx.Dialog.Destroy()`):

```
        ...
        self.dia = Dialog(self)

    def onButton(self, evt):
        self.dia.ShowModal()
```

Am I experiencing a limitation with the Gtk UI that cannot be circumvented? All the suggestions I have come across say to use `Refresh()` & `Update()`. But these are not working for me. I have also tried using `wx.GetApp().Yield()` before calling `ShowModal()`.

- [How do you force refresh of a wx.Panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230630/how-do-you-force-refresh-of-a-wx-panel)
- [Python GUI does not update until entire process is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939675/python-gui-does-not-update-until-entire-process-is-finished)
- https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/problem-updating-widget-immediately-with-layout-and-update/34452

**Edit:** Here is a screenshot of the dialog showing how the text is off center & not fully displayed:

[image: off center text]

If I remove the call to `panel1.Layout()` The text is fully displayed but still not centered. If I use `SetSizerAndFit` instead of `SetSizer` & `SetAutoLayout` some space is allocated above for the spacer, but text is still not centered:

```
    ...
        #panel1.SetSizer(layout1)
        #panel1.SetAutoLayout(True)
        #panel1.Layout()
        panel1.SetSizerAndFit(layout1)
    ...
```

[image: off center with fit]

Comment: you are using `ShowModal()` - why do you need to call ``Destroy()`? Please check the documentation of `wxPython` on how to get the value of responce from modal dialog.

Comment: Using modal dialog implies you want to have a user response and then depending on it - either perform some action or not. Check the documentation/ sample code on how to do that.

Comment: I don't need to call `Destroy()`.

Comment: Oh, you think `Destroy()` is closing the dialog before user input? No. That doesn't get called until after the dialog is closed by the user. The only reason it is included is to demonstrate how the dialog's layout is reset when it is used.

Comment: are you saying you actual code doesn't call `Destroy()`? Can you post you actual code, please?

Comment: That is the actual code. `Destroy()` can be removed & the only change is that once the dialog opens with the correct layout it will do the same on opening subsequently. Calling `Destroy()` after `ShowModal()` does not immediately destroy a modal window. It waits for the user to close it before it is destroyed.

Comment: you don't need to call `Destroy()`. Running modal dialog - the dialog object will be created on the stack and will be destroyed when the variable will go out of scope. Are you saying that it is not the case and `Destroy()` is required?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. "`Destroy()` can be removed & the only change is that once the dialog opens with the correct layout it will do the same on opening subsequently." I'll comment `Destroy()` from the code so there is no more confusion. My problem is the children of the `wx.Notebook` class are not laying out correctly.

Comment: yes, please do as it is confusing. To solve your problem - call Layout at the end of the dialog constructor.

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried it on the dialog, the notebook, & the panel.

Comment: can you remove the call to `Destroy()`, call `Layout()` at the end of the dialog constructor and post the screenshot of what is produced? You can also try calling `SetSizerAndFit()`, instead of calling `SetSizer() && SetAutoLayout() && Layout()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within the version of wxPython (4.0.7). It works correctly with 4.1.1 (installed via PyPI as Ubuntu repos do not provide a later version yet).